# What's Google Inbox request/response obfuscation skill?

Tags: encryption, network, obfuscation

I Inspected Google Inbox network resources via Chrome Developer Tool.
I saw some request/response payload and result.
[image: Inbox's request payload]

This object type is not readable for human. I've never seen this kind of security. Is this general dev stack? It looks very safe.

Comment: This is no security measure (as that would be security through obscurity). I assume, given the documentation to it, this payload can make lots of sense.

Comment: @marstato Is it not security way? Then I'm really curious at why they implemented like that even if there's easier way.

Comment: [Security through obsucrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) *is* a kind of security; but it wont resist a determined and skilled attacker (which is the kind of attacker that targets Google imho) I believe that all of this makes sense once one gets a glance at the documentation to it. What was the request URI for that payload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This object type is not readable for human.

Why should it? It is intended for a computer and not for a human.

> I've never seen this kind of security. Is this general dev stack? It looks very safe.

I doubt that this is primary a security feature. My guess is that they use some higher level development tool which just generates this kind of stuff. The aim is not to be readable by a human but to provide efficient processing by a machine - which often includes that it looks strange for humans. Such higher level tools not only speed up development but also often deal with the security problems better than handcrafted code.